# Conversation connector / Watson Assistant: How to change account or workspace?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant, watson-conversation, ibm-cloud-functions

I am using the [Conversation connector](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-connector) to implement a [Slackbot with Watson Assistant](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/slack-chatbot-database-watson.html). I want to move the chatbot over to another account and workspace. How can I do that without redeploying the Conversation connector and changing something in Slack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I can edit the [configuration document stored in the described **authdb**](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-connector).

1. In the [IBM Cloud dashboard](https://console.bluemix.net/dashboard/apps) locate the Cloudant service named **conversation-connector**.
2. Click on that service and go to the Cloudant dashboard.
3. Click on the **authdb** database. There should be a single doc in it.
4. Edit the section **conversation** and adapt the username / password / workspace_id to the new values.
5. Save changes. Done.